# the import net can not be solved for "net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils"

Tags: java, jframe

I'm using eclipse 2018-09 version. in my project, I've added rs2xml jar for using data from dataset to jtable. But when I import `net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils` it showing error and the message is

> the import net cannot be resolved

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Provide more details

Comment: In eclipse, to show data from database in jTable, I used rs2xml.jar. In the jar, DbUtils class has to work for showing the data in the table. But when I include the file in the code, it showing error. It says "import net cannot be resolved"